# Heap memory usage for Openssl

Tags: c, openssl, heap-memory, valgrind

I have a simple HTTPS server implemented with Openssl library in C. The heap usage seems huge for a single connection. The following are some objects that might take big heap space:

- `char readbuffer[8192]`
- `SSL_CTX`
- `SSL`

Is this normal? Is there a tool that can find out which object takes how much heap?

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==7644==     in use at exit: 78,502 bytes in 2,366 blocks
==7644==   total heap usage: 3,548 allocs, 1,182 frees, 3,139,689 bytes allocated
==7644==
==7644== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7644==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7644==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7644==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7644==    still reachable: 78,502 bytes in 2,366 blocks
==7644==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try figuring out which malloc calls are made and when. Dmalloc can help: http://dmalloc.com/

One time I also used a simple wrapper script to track memory allocations manually. I think it was this one:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c